# How to calculate theoretical running time for a created algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, loops, runtime, big-o

I need some help analyzing my algorithm to determine its theoretical running time. I think I understand how to analyze most of it. I'm not sure how to analyze the **while loop** that contains a **for loop**. Ill provide my algorithm, followed by what I think/know.

---

### My Algorithm:

```
def getD(a):
    corrections = [] #list for correction values
    comparisons = 0 #comparison counter

    #initialize corrections list with all 0's
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        corrections.append(0)

    flag = True #loop control

    while(flag):
        flag = False
        #loop through list
        for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
            current = a[i] #current element value
            nxt = a[i+1] #next element value
            dif = nxt - (current + 1)

            #correct the nxt item.. i+1. comparisons++
            if(dif < 0):
                comparisons += 1
                corrections[i+1] -= dif
                a[i+1] -= dif
                flag = True

    d = int((max(corrections)+1)/2)

    #balance the corrections
    for i in range(len(a)):
        corrections[i] -= d
    print(d)
    print("Number of comparisons:",comparisons)
```

---

### My progressing analysis:

n = length of the input list (a)

The dominating operations are the 3 for loops and the while loop.

The first **for loop** iterates n times.. so it has a running time of **n.**

The last for loop also iterates n times.. applying the corrections to each element, so it also has a running time of **n.**

---

For the 2 **for loops** above.. I think the combined running time would be 2n? But there's more to add for the entire algorithm running time.

Here's where I start to struggle:

The dominating operations left (I believe) is the **while** loop with the **for** loop inside.The **for** loop will run **at most** n-1 times. But if dif < 0, it runs the for loop starting with i=0 again.

I'm not sure what the run time for this part would be or the algorithm as a whole. How do I calculate the while with the last for loop in it? How would I combine them all together?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Cool @JohnSaunders thanks for enforcing every rule.

Comment: Not enforcing, just informing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `for` loop always runs for n iterations and is therefore O(n).

Your last `for` loop always runs for n iterations and is therefore O(n).

Your middle `for` loop (inside the `while` loop) always runs for n - 1 iterations and is therefore O(n).

Now, how many iterations will `while` loop execute? It appears to be variable, but let's take a closer look at the inner `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
    current = a[i] #current element value
    nxt = a[i+1] #next element value
    dif = nxt - (current + 1)

    #correct the nxt item.. i+1. comparisons++
    if(dif < 0):
        comparisons += 1
        corrections[i+1] -= dif
        a[i+1] -= dif
        flag = True
```

So, on the first pass through this `for` loop, `i == 0`. The `if` statement ensures that `a[1] ≥ a[0] + 1`, by setting `a[1] = a[0] + 1` if necessary.

On the second pass, `i == 1`. The `if` statement ensures that `a[2] ≥ a[1] + 1`, by setting `a[2]` if necessary.

On the third pass, `i == 2`. The `if` statement ensures that `a[3] ≥ a[2] + 1`, by setting `a[3]` if necessary.

Notice that on every pass, the loop can set `a[i+1]`, but no earlier elements.  Thus each pass through the inner `for` loop can never undo the work of a previous pass.

When this inner `for` loop stops executing, `a[i+1] ≥ a[i] + 1` for all `i`.

The `while` loop is guaranteed to run at least once. If the inner `for` loop makes any changes to the array, it sets `flag`, making the `while` loop execute a second time. On the second pass through the `while` loop, the array is already fully groomed, so `flag` will remain `False`.

Therefore the `while` loop executes at most two iterations, so it is O(2n) (the n comes from the O(n) complexity of the inner `for` loop).  And you probably know that O(2n) == O(n).

All the outer loops in your `getD` function are O(n), so your function is itself O(n).

By the way, you can initialize `corrections` like this in Python:

```
corrections = [0] * len(a)
```